# php is not adding data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $qry = "INSERT INTO `guest` (`name`, `pincode`, `address`, `phone`, `date`) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['name']."', '".$_SESSION['pincode']."', '".$_SESSION['address']."', '".$_SESSION['phone']."', '".$date."');";
        $result = $conn->query($qry);
        //echo $qry;
        $qry = "select guest_id from guest where name = '".$_SESSION['name']."' and pincode = '".$_SESSION['pincode']."' and address= '".$_SESSION['address']."' and phone= '".$_SESSION['phone']."' and date= '".$date."';";
        //echo $qry;
        $result = $conn->query($qry);
        $row = $result -> fetch_assoc();
        //echo $row['guest_id'];
        $guest_id = $row['guest_id'];
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        //$qry1 = "INSERT INTO order (`order_date`, `payment_type`, `payment_status`, `order_status`, `order_type`, `amount`, `cust_id`) VALUES ('".$date."', 'cod', 'yes', 'Pending', 'yes', ".$_SESSION['total'].", '".$guest_id."');";
        $qry1 = "INSERT INTO `grocery`.`order` (`order_date`, `payment_type`, `payment_status`, `order_status`, `delivery_slot`, `order_type`, `amount`, `deliver_date`, `cust_id`) VALUES ('sd', 'asd', 'sdf', 'sd', '4', 'sf', '23', '2017-04-19', 'sdfs');";

        $result1 = $conn->query($qry1);
        echo $qry1;
```

The first 2 queries are getting executed and data is added to db.. But the last statement is not adding the data to db. Please help me out

Comment: Getting Any error?

Comment: no errors are coming

Comment: @deepakasai you wanna select after inserting?

Comment: What library is $conn from? PDO?

Comment: Please take some time today to learn about SQL Injection attacks. The code you are writing looks as though it may be susceptible. You should use a method for inserting values into your queries that includes prepared statements and bindings.

Comment: the columns 'deliver_slot' and 'amount': are they integers? If yes, **remove the quotes** for the values of these columns ('4' and '23') and try again as (4 and 23).

Comment: You have echo your `$qry1`, Simply copy and paste this result in mysql and see if query is executing or not

Comment: is your table name right? looks odd to me

Comment: See... the same query if i execute in mysql its working.. But not via php. this is my problem.. yea i have removed quotes also and checked...

Comment: What's the point of the $guest_id bit?

Comment: It's perverse; in your commented out query, the one identifier you failed to backtick was the only one that needed them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume `$conn` is a `PDO` object.

I have a few recommendations:

1) Use a higher level database abstraction. DBAL is really nice.

2) If you're going to use PDO, you have to check the return value of `$conn->query()` for  `false` to know if an error occurred, then call `$conn->errorInfo` and `$conn->errorCode` to know what that error was. You should always handle error conditions in function calls.

3) Instead of handling error conditions, PDO can be configured to throw exceptions by using:

```
$conn->setAttribute("PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE", PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

This means you have less error handling code to write if you simply want to abort on DB errors.

Comment: it is not pdo.. its mysqli object oriented.. so how to get error report in this??

Comment: you can use mysqli_error() or mysqli_connect_error() for displaying error , if there are any one.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the issue of SQL injection to one side, for just a moment, it seems to me that everything after line 3 could be replaced with this:

```
        INSERT INTO `order` 
        (order_date
        ,payment_type
        ,payment_status
        ,order_status
        ,order_type
        ,amount
        ,cust_id) 
        SELECT CURDATE()
             , 'cod'
             , 'yes'
             , 'Pending'
             , 'yes'
             , {$_SESSION['total']}
             , guest_id
          FROM guest 
         WHERE name    = '{$_SESSION['name']}' 
           AND pincode = '{$_SESSION['pincode']}' 
           AND address = '{$_SESSION['address']}' 
           AND phone   = '{$_SESSION['phone']}' 
           AND date    = CURDATE();
```